# Read string one char at a time until end of line or file

Tags: c++, input, char

So, I need to read several lines of numbers from `stdin` char-by-char; that is, after each char read I need to do something to it and only after that I can read another one; I also need to know when the line ends and another starts. Those numbers are newline-separated and I have no problem with that; but there is no `\n` after the last string, so I have a problem with determining when to stop reading the last line. I feel really stupid, but googling didn't help me at all. I assume it should be something like this:

```
char b;
for (size_t i = 0; i!= N; ++i) {
    while (some_mysterious_condition) {
        std::cin >> b;
        //so on
    }
```

I can't figure out what condition I should put there. I've tried using `std::cin.get(b)`, but it seems to ignore newlines.

Comment: [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) does what you're looking for.

Comment: what is there after the last string? By default cin considers all whitespaces including EOF.as deliminator. BTW what are you trying to solve? If you want to read strings why are you reading data into a char?

Comment: @bashrc nothing, the file ends there. And, if you really have to know, though this has no relation to the topic in question, I'm reading BigInteger numbers digit by digit

Comment: To read the lines one character at a time, read in with getline, load the line in a std::istringstream and read from that.  That way you read per line and you read all the characters.

Comment: @stefaanv ...and I waste a lot of time and memory reading into a string and back out of it. Or, if I read one char at a time, I won't know where the line ends, right?

Comment: This becomes only problematic if you are reading in a huge number of lines.  Otherwise, you are wasting development time looking for the most performant solution while hopefully reading in data is not the core part of your application.

Comment: @stefaanv How about some million lines several thousands characters each?

Comment: Then it might help to use [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) and interprete all characters yourself.  But remember that the code will always be less maintainable and more error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, looks like you need to read characters?

```
char b;
for (size_t i = 0; i!= N; ++i) {
    while (some_mysterious_condition && std::cin >> b) {

        //so on
    }
```

cin will return false when it encounters EOF(which is the character which denotes the end of file/stream).

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just check to see if the value of the last char read is equal to '\0'and then break?

Edit:

Something like this then:

```
char b;

for (;;) {
    for (;;)
    {
        b = std::cin.get();
        if ((b == '\0') || (b == '\n')) {
            //new line or end of file was found, skip handling that character
            break;
        }
         //do something with char b
    }

    if (b == '\0') break; //exit outer loop if end of file detected

}
```

Comment: "I've tried using std::cin.get(b), but it seems to ignore newlines." And this is the only way I managed to catch the end of file correctly

Comment: So you want to read each line char by char but detect either a newline or end of file at every point along the way.